# R programming spectrum analysis

Tags: r

hello am new to R programming in r studio . I will be analyzing the spectral data of raman spectrum in future. 
which package will be useful to for the spectral data analysis.I would like to learn that package. I have attached the image how I want to analyze. Please give me suggestions, how to plot the graph as shown in the fig in r studio

thanks in advance [image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. While I completely get that you're question could be useful, it might be a bit too open to receive a proper answer. Asking for packages tend to attract opinionated answers and are therefore not within the scope of Stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Try to rephrase your question as a more specific problem. For example, I am using package X but can't seem to find a way to do Y (with a reproducible code).

Comment: @Tanveer "I have attached the image how I want to analyze" - If you would like to link specific bands to molecular vibrations of real biological material, you would hardly find any packages that do that sort of things. This is a really complex task and requires expertize in Raman spectroscopy of bio molecules. The typical workflow in R focuses instead on statistical analysis of variations between spectra. You can use this knowledge to predict a new sample or to understand what the differences between samples are. However, often you cannot say what is the actual composition of the sample.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free package called `hyperSpec` that was specifically designed to handle spectral data together with associated extra data (e.g. experimental parameters etc.). The package also provides interface for common operations, like baseline correction, selection of spectral ranges, normalization, PCA, etc. Moreover, there is a host of plotting functions.

You can install it from CRAN with `install.packages("hyperSpec")`, however, as of today the CRAN version is outdated. I would recommend you to fetch the [recent build from gitHub](https://github.com/cbeleites/hyperSpec/releases/) and install it via Rstudio (look for *packages->install->from package archive file*).

`hyperSpec` comes with an extensive documentation and example datasets. To browse through tutorials, run

```
browseVignettes("hyperSpec")
```

Plotting is as easy as

```
plot(chondro)  # left plot
qplotspc(chondro) + ggtitle("Example dataset")  # right plot
```

[image: Sample plot]

To import your own data, look for functions inside of hyperSpec, whose name starts with `read`. Just start typing `hyperSpec::read` and a pop-up will appear. A lot of device-specific data formats are supported. See `vignette("fileio")` for details.